# iphone how to specify the Class data type have to adopt to a protocol

Tags: iphone, objective-c, protocols

In my application, I need to return the "Class" as a return type like:

Application.m:

```
+ (Class)getParserClass {
  return [NCCurrencyParser class];
}
```

NCCurrencyParser.m:

```
@interface NCCurrencyParser NSObject <NCParser>
@protocol NCParser
  +(NSNumber *)parserNumber:(NSNumber *)number;
```

in the caller method:

```
Class parserClass = [Application getParserClass];
[parserClass parserNumber:1.0];
```

But then the compiler gives me the error that parserClass may not respond to parseNumber.  How can I force the Class have to adopt to some protocol like : `Class <NCParser>` (but it doesn't work)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Class** objects in Objective-C are **first class** objects, and can can implement protocols like any other Objective-C object (id, NSObject*, ...)

So just do whatever you would normally do for any other Object protocol, ie:

```
+ (Class<NCParser>)getParserClass {
  return [NCCurrencyParser class];
}
```

And

```
Class<NCParser> parserClass = [Application getParserClass];
[parserClass parserNumber:1.0];
```

*Build/Compiled/Tested on xcode 3.2.3, iPhone Simulator 4.0, GCC 4.2*

Comment: Hey look! its just what i said to do :)

Comment: I didn't mean to take credit for your good answer (+1), but since it seemed to be in dispute, I though it best to actually see what the actual behavior was.

Comment: No, just screwin around, thanks for actually testing it. (+1)

Comment: Oh men, something was wrong with my code. The last time I tried it, it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

What is going on...this just seems VERY wrong.

But doing `Class<NCParser> parserClass = [Application getParserClass];` should work

Comment: This will not work. `conformToProtocol:` method just works for an `NCObject` or `id` object, not for `Class` object.

Comment: Actually, any `Class` can be cast to id.

Comment: "any Class can be cast to id" really? Did you check?

Comment: This all screams of an underlying design issue anyway. What are you actually trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

> "But then the compiler gives me the
>   error that parserClass may not respond
>   to parseNumber"

If you just need to ignore the error message.
Put this in the class which has the caller method:

```
#import "NCParser.h"
```

will solve your problem. It just works!

I think XCode bases on your import to determine the methods for `Class`.

> "How can I force the Class have to
>   adopt to some protocol like : Class"

You can check a `NCObject` or `id` conform to a protocol at compile time using `id <AProtocol>`. But I don't think you can do that for a `Class` object.

My approach is check it in runtime. Like this:

```
NSObject *object = [[class alloc] init];
NSAssert ([object conformsToProtocol:@protocol(AProtocol)], 
          @"`class` should conform AProtocol");
```

Comment: **"you just need to ignore the error message"**. 

 "We must be very careful when we give advice to younger people: sometimes they follow it!" **Edsger W Dijkstra:**